# uispec4j testing application java

Tags: java, testing, uispec4j

i have a little application, Phonebook, and i want test it.
i have some problem with uispec4j, i write this:

```
public class TestRubricaBlack extends UISpecTestCase{

@BeforeClass
public void setUp(){
    setAdapter(new MainClassAdapter(Rubrica.class, new String[0]));

}

public void testMamma(){

    Window window=getMainWindow();
    assertEquals(true,window.getButton("index").isVisible());
}
}
```

when i try to execute the test, i have this error, the problem is on function getMainWindow():

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.uispec4j.utils.TriggerRunner.runInCurrentThread(TriggerRunner.java:18)
    at org.uispec4j.interception.WindowInterceptor.run(WindowInterceptor.java:320)
    at org.uispec4j.interception.WindowInterceptor.run(WindowInterceptor.java:290)
    at org.uispec4j.interception.MainClassAdapter.getMainWindow(MainClassAdapter.java:24)
    at org.uispec4j.UISpecTestCase.getMainWindow(UISpecTestCase.java:84)
    at it.is2.TestRubricaBlack.testMamma(TestRubricaBlack.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.uispec4j.utils.MainClassTrigger.run(MainClassTrigger.java:22)
    at org.uispec4j.utils.TriggerRunner.runInCurrentThread(TriggerRunner.java:12)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: peer
    at sun.awt.windows.WTextFieldPeer.create(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.<init>(WComponentPeer.java:595)
    at sun.awt.windows.WTextComponentPeer.<init>(WTextComponentPeer.java:36)
    at sun.awt.windows.WTextFieldPeer.<init>(WTextFieldPeer.java:65)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.createTextField(WToolkit.java:332)
    at org.uispec4j.interception.toolkit.ToolkitDelegate.createTextField(ToolkitDelegate.java:262)
    at java.awt.TextField.addNotify(TextField.java:205)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2592)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4683)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2592)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4683)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2592)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4683)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2592)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4683)
    at javax.swing.JRootPane.addNotify(JRootPane.java:735)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2592)
    at java.awt.Window.addNotify(Window.java:638)
    at java.awt.Frame.addNotify(Frame.java:469)
    at java.awt.Window.show(Window.java:823)
    at it.is2.Rubrica.main(Rubrica.java:26)
    ... 30 more
```

can someone help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace tells me the button named "index" was not found.  Not being psychic or having your code available, I have no idea why.  Here are my best guesses:

1. You did not define a button named "index"
2. You misspelled the name
3. The button is defined on a panel and not directly on the main window

I am having trouble with the third item, which is how I came across your post.  I may be wrong, but it seems that uispec4j does not automatically look in containers like panels and, in my case, JScrollPanes.

If I find I am wrong about this behavior, I will update my reply.  If I come up with a solution, maybe a custom matcher, I will post it as well.

Good luck.

Comment: I am wrong!  I had a type in the name of my component.  uispec4j will search the component hierarchy and find the component in sub-panels.  So check for item 1 or 2.